# What is --export-secret-subkeys used for?

Tags: gnupg

From the [docs](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Operational-GPG-Commands.html):

> `--export-secret-keys`
> `--export-secret-subkeys`
>
> Same as `--export`, but exports the secret keys instead. The exported keys are written to STDOUT or to the file given with option
> `--output`. This command is often used along with the option `--armor` to allow for easy printing of the key for paper backup; however the
> external tool paperkey does a better job of creating backups on paper.
> Note that exporting a secret key can be a security risk if the
> exported keys are sent over an insecure channel.
>
> The second form of the command has the special property to render the secret part of the primary key useless; this is a GNU extension to
> OpenPGP and other implementations can not be expected to successfully
> import such a key. Its intended use is in generating a full key with
> an additional signing subkey on a dedicated machine. This command then
> exports the key without the primary key to the main machine.
>
> GnuPG may ask you to enter the passphrase for the key. This is required, because the internal protection method of the secret key is
> different from the one specified by the OpenPGP protocol.

I don’t understand what "The second form of the command has the special property..." means and I spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure it out searching the web.

Trying to figure out if using `--export-secret-keys` includes master and subkeys (in the context of backing up both). This is sensitive stuff... want to make sure I have my facts straight.

Can someone please ELI5?

Comment: You could compare the outputs of `gpg --export-secret-keys | gpg --list-packets` and `gpg --export-secret-subkeys | gpg --list-packets`. The second form will give you a `gnu-dummy S2K` instead of the real primary secret key.

Answer (score 8):

It means that the `--export-secret-subkeys` option (*second form of the command*) will export dummy packets for the primary key, so effectly only **sub** keys are exported.

See also [this guide from Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Subkeys) (search "dummy OpenPGP packet").